# Issue getting program to run JAVA

Tags: java, applet

I am having issues trying to get this program to run,  I can't seem to find where my error(s) are,  can anyone help?  When I run the program,  I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
atjava.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
at LargestApplet.init(LargestApplet.java:40)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I can't seem to figure out what exactly I am doing wrong.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


    public class LargestApplet extends Applet implements ActionListener {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        int number =0;
        double highNumber=-1;
        double lowNumber=-1;



        // Create components for applet
        Label numberLabel = new Label("Enter a number:");
        TextField numberField = new TextField(5);
        Button okButton;
        Button cancelButton;
        Label highNumberOutputLabel = new Label("The Highest number is: 0         ");

        public void init() {
            add(numberLabel);
            add(numberField);
            numberField.requestFocus();
            add(okButton);
            add(cancelButton);
            add(highNumberOutputLabel);
            setSize(400, 500);  // Sets the size of the applet window
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int number = 0, highNumber = -1;

            if (numberField.getText().length() == 0) {
                numberField.requestFocus();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Number Cannot blank", "D A T A   E R R O R",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return;
            }
            try {
                number = Integer.parseInt(numberField.getText());
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                numberField.requestFocus();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Number is invalid",
                        "D A T A   E R R O R", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return;
            }
            if (number < 0 || number > 10) {
                numberField.requestFocus();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Number must be between 0 and 10",
                        "D A T A   E R R O R", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return;
            }
            // Determine highest number
            Integer [] numberAr = {number};
            for(int i = 0; i < numberAr.length; i++)
            {
                number += numberAr[i];
                if (numberAr[i] < lowNumber)
                    lowNumber = numberAr[i];
                else if (numberAr[i] > highNumber)
                    highNumber = numberAr[i];
            }

            // Display the results
            highNumberOutputLabel.setText("The Highest Number is:   "
                    + (highNumber));




}
        }
```

Comment: The exception stack trace message is telling you exactly where the problem is occurring: `LargestApplet.java:40` or line 40 of your class. Check the code on that line and find the offending null variable, and then fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to previously initialize both Button objects before adding to the Applet's content pane.

Also, your Applet isn't "listening" to the events generated by the buttons, you also need to check what type of event is being processed in the *actionPerformed* method.

I know I shouldn't give you the fish straight away, but here's a possible solution:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class LargestApplet extends Applet implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    int number =0;
    double highNumber=-1;
    double lowNumber=-1;



    // Create components for applet
    Label numberLabel = new Label("Enter a number:");
    TextField numberField = new TextField(5);
    Button okButton = new Button("OK");
    Button cancelButton = new Button("Cancel");
    Label highNumberOutputLabel = new Label("The Highest number is: 0         ");

    public void init() {
        add(numberLabel);
        add(numberField);
        numberField.requestFocus();

        add(okButton);
        add(cancelButton);
        add(highNumberOutputLabel);

        okButton.addActionListener(this);
        cancelButton.addActionListener(this);

        okButton.setActionCommand("ok");
        cancelButton.setActionCommand("cancel");

        setSize(400, 500);  // Sets the size of the applet window
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int number = 0, highNumber = -1;

        String command = e.getActionCommand();

        if(command.equals("cancel"))
            System.exit(0);

        if (numberField.getText().length() == 0) {
            numberField.requestFocus();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Number Cannot blank", "D A T A   E R R O R",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }
        try {
            number = Integer.parseInt(numberField.getText());
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            numberField.requestFocus();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Number is invalid",
                    "D A T A   E R R O R", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }
        if (number < 0 || number > 10) {
            numberField.requestFocus();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Number must be between 0 and 10",
                    "D A T A   E R R O R", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }
        // Determine highest number
        Integer [] numberAr = {number};
        for(int i = 0; i < numberAr.length; i++)
        {
            number += numberAr[i];
            if (numberAr[i] < lowNumber)
                lowNumber = numberAr[i];
            else if (numberAr[i] > highNumber)
                highNumber = numberAr[i];
        }

        // Display the results
        highNumberOutputLabel.setText("The Highest Number is:   "
                + (highNumber));
    }
}
```

You should study the **AWT** and **Swing** libraries in order to understand some key concepts and design patterns. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to add buttons which are not initialized

```
 add(okButton);
 add(cancelButton);
```

You should initialize both of them before adding them

```
Button okButton = new Button(..);
Button cancelButton = new Button(..);
```

Comment: OK< thank you,  I did find that issue,  Now it doesn't seem to "store" my inputs?